# Can we achieve a better performance than CSS3 transitions?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm working on a big resolution slider (big pictures / html5 canvases as items). Unfortunately I can't show a actual project but I prepared [a little demo](http://codepen.io/emiljas/pen/BjOOdq).

```
.slider {
    transform-origin: left top;
    transition: transform 1s ease;
    transform: scale(0.33, 0.33);
    width: 4000px;
    height: 2000px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.slider:hover {
    transform: scale(0.33, 0.33) translate(1000px);
}
```

Can we achieve a better performance than this e.g. in C language in OpenGL? Can we in browser (css3, canvas or WebGL or ..)? I will be grateful for any examples.

Comment: What are your performance concerns exactly? Wouldn't either way still be heavily dependent on the specs of the target machine?

Comment: @ChrisW. I run demo on several machines. On the most performant one i achive 50-60FPS. I'm looking for way which achive 59-60FPS on at least one machine ;) I'm planning to build same demo in C and OpenGL to compare this two demos on same machines.

Comment: When you do, if you have a blog or something, please post results and the benchmarks you use for testing. I'm sure I wouldn't be the only one interested in the conclusion. Cheers! :)

Comment: I'd try Flickity, which puts a huge emphasis on making transitions as smooth as possible: http://flickity.metafizzy.co/ Desandro did a ton of work on the physics side of this plugin - I've used it with great success.